# Libreoffice Writer, how to get read-only a document part

Tags: readonly, libreoffice

I am writing a document with Libreoffice Writer. I would like to set a part of it as read-only, while the rest of the document as non-read-only.

Is it possible to do it?
How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can insert a "section" (Menu `Insert` -> `Section...`) and set that section read-only:

[image]

The OpenOffice.org Wiki has more information about [using sections for page layout](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_sections_for_page_layout).

Comment: In a nutshell: you can later toggle the protection through Format → Sections... and you can select a bunch of existing text when creating a section (that selection will be moved into the new section).

Comment: @tohuwawohu Thanx, you're right :-)